# WebDriverManager cannot be resolved

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, webdrivermanager-java

Created Maven project in Eclipse IDE. I added this following dependency. I am getting WebDriverManager unable to resolve error. Can please  help in resolving this issue.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
    <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks

Comment: Update the question with the complete error stacktrace.

Comment: ...should that have - be mapped to a download url?